# Science fiction series (on the Sci-Fi Channel, I think) with a team of scientists trying to track down aliens among us. One is in a wheelchair

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I watched this probably in the early to mid 1990s, in the early days of the Sci-Fi Channel (before they became [*Syfy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syfy)) at my grandmother's house. The protagonists were a set of 4-5 people in a team, I think government-sponsored, that were fighting some aliens that had infiltrated Earth, and could appear human. One of the team was a man in a wheelchair. Early in the episode, some people in the team were training in staff fighting and a staff got thrown to the guy in the wheelchair, I think with a joke made, either by him or another member of the team, that obviously the training didn't apply to him. I think he produced his own staff, and showed that he could hold his own from in the chair, revealing near the end that he'd "cheated" by using a custom staff that had a metal core to add to its weight and inertia.

Near the end of the episode, he winds up trapped with one of the aliens, who has revealed their identity, and the fight looks like it's going against him until he arranges for his staff to be broken (the wooden covering, at least) and then gets the alien to impale itself on one end with the other end jammed into some equipment, resulting in the alien getting electrocuted. I think as a result of this episode, it seemed that the rest of the team respected him more now that he'd shown that he could defend himself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could this be the TV series War of the Worlds?

- The dates are a close match (1988-1990)
- Team of 5 (season 1) fighting aliens who have invaded Earth
- Norton Drake is a paraplegic computer genius who is granted mobility via a voice-activated wheelchair named Gertrude.

Comment: Also features aliens that can inhabit human bodies,

Comment: And, with that in hand, it looks like the episode is "S01E11 - Among the Philistines”. I erred on who did the staff trick, but the metal core and the electrical panel are there. Thank you.